# Azure Function - How can I use context.log in classes?

Tags: azure, debugging, logging, azure-functions, alexa-skills-kit

To preface, I'm trying to run an Alexa skill in an Azure function.

I'm currently having issues debugging the Azure Function I have running.

When I'm in the httpTrigger part of the codebase, I can utilize `context.log` as much as I want.

```
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
```

The issue I'm having is, this function wraps around an entire codebase.  I'm not sure how to initialize the context.log functionality in a class.

```
export class Foo {

}
```

I've seen some documentation stating I can initialize logging in the `host.json` file, but I've had no luck so far.

Is there any way I can utilize context.log?  I've encountered some issues that can only be resolved with the ability to put logs in the codebase.

If not, how can I debug my code?  I can't use console.log.  It's not showing up when I try monitoring the function on Azure Portal.

Comment: If you want to debug the code you can try Integrating Application insights into your code.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  Trying to setup now.  Does this allow me to insert ```console.log``` throughout the code?  Or something similar?  From what I can gather, it seems like it does some sort of automated monitoring of the app/function, but I'm not sure if it will pinpoint where in my code something is going wrong.

Comment: I seem to have Application Insights working now, but the logs are cut off.  It seems like it doesn't give me enough information in the "Sample telemetry" section.

Comment: Have u enabled application insights settings  inside Azure functions.

Comment: Below is the code to setup telemetry client
// Setup Telemetry
TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
telemetry.InstrumentationKey = //Your application insights instrumentation key
var time = DateTime.Now;
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
//send result to App Insights
telemetry.TrackRequest(requestname, time, sw.Elapsed, “200”, true);

Comment: You need to pass this telemetry object to your code base and use different methods of telemetry client to log information,exceptions inside
Application Insights.Note : It takes some amount of time for information/errors to log inside Azure Application Insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If not, how can I debug my code? I can't use console.log. It's not showing up when I try monitoring the function on Azure Portal.

You can get this to work if you install and setup my NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-function-log-intercept

Passing `context` everywhere in your codebase was something I found to be extremely cumbersome so I made that package.